# Definition of star in a simplicial complex

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

Given a simplicial complex K and a collection of simplices S in K, the star of S is defined as the set of all simplices that have a face in S. Now consider the following picture (from wikipedia):

[image: Star of a complex]

In the picture, S consists of the yellow point and its star is shown in green on the right.

Now it appears that this is somewhat of a convention, but the edges which are opposite of S in the green triangles are not part of the star of S. I find this confusing because I thought that they were parts of 2-simplices, the triangles which are shaded. The edges, when considered as 1-simplices in their own right, certainly do not contain S as a face, but the 2-simplices which contain them do contain S as a face.

So, a question. In diagrams like this, why do we exclude edges like this from the star? Aren't each of them a part of a 2-simplex which contains S?

Comment: You describe the open star, which, as you note, is *not* a subcomplex. There is also the closed star, which is the subcomplex that you would have preferred. Both are useful notions. Also the complement of the open star is a subcomplex, and its intersection with the closed star is called the *link*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One needs to distinguish between an abstract simplicial complex and its geometric realization. We are dealing with the former here, so that we are thinking of a simplex as a collection of vertices. The correspondence to the geometric realization is probably best visualized by taking the interiors of simplices.

Comment: Is it possible to have a 2-dimensional simplicial complex that does not have a geometric realization? And if so, can we still think of chains and cochains in the space? I am thinking specifically of the building that the special linear group of 3 by 3 matrices with p-adic entries acts on. (I just added a new question about it, but I wanted to ask you, too.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion might be in expecting the star of S to be closed in the sense: for every simplex in the star, the faces of that simplex should also be there.

The star is not defined in that way, and in general the star by itself is not a simplicial complex.

There is also no convention involved: you add the simplex if it has a face in S. As you point out, those edges do not contain S as a face, so you do not add them.

Answer (score 1):

Munkres = Munkres J. R.: *Elementary Differential Topology*, 2nd ed., Princeton: Princeton University Press, 1968.
Dugundji = Dugundji, J.: *Topology*, Boston: Allyn and Bacon, 1966.

The openness of St (x,K) [Munkres, p.70, l.11--l.12] follows from [Dugundji, p.172, l.−15]. This is the only place where I have found the most direct and effective definition and proof for the star of a vertex. For details, see Example 6.162 in https://sites.google.com/view/lcwangpress/%E9%A6%96%E9%A0%81/papers/mathematical-methods and the first four lines of §35.II in https://sites.google.com/view/lcwangpress/%E9%A6%96%E9%A0%81/papers/mathematical-proofs.

Comment: Consider elaborating a little more, if necessary by quoting from Munkres and Dugundji. Your answer was flagged for being low-quality and while I don't think it is so in any way, I believe that the length may have contributed to this particular aspect. I will appreciate this effort with an up vote when I can, thanks.